# Finding average time to add a user?

Tags: excel

So I have a pivot table that looks like this:

ID | Users in Month 0 | Users in Month 1 | ... | Users in Month 50

Each row is a company ID and each column is a record of their # of users in their first month, second month, etc. Obviously some companies have longer histories (more columns) than others.

I'd like to find the average time that it takes for a company to gain a user based on this monthly record. What was the average amount of time for them to go from 0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, etc. But I'm at a loss for how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a column to the left of column A.

Fill down this formula:

`=((MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(C1:DA1),0,0),0))-1)/SUM(C1:DA1)`

(I assume you have blanks in the cells for which you don't have data, and that you have data for all months from start to finish (whatever the finish is) for each company -- i.e. no gaps.)

The numerator of this fraction is the number of months for which you have data for that company (row). The denominator is the total number of users over all of the months for that particular company.

The result is the average time (in months) to acquire one user for that company.

This formula is good for 77 months' worth of data. If you need more, change the `DA1`'s out to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the difference in numbers rather than the sum - so if the numbers are in row 2

```
(Position of last number-position of first number)/(last number-first number)
```

Suppose you had a sheet with the pivot table in it like this

[image]

Then you could get the average time per added user like this

```
=(MATCH(9E+99,Pivot!5:5)-MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(Pivot!5:5),0),0))/
(LOOKUP(9E+99,Pivot!5:5)-INDEX(Pivot!5:5,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(Pivot!5:5),0),0)))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]